# Sorting a DataGridView by DataGridViewComboxBoxColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to be able to sort a DataGridView by the ComboBoxColumn so I can display groups based on the value in the ComboBoxColumn. When I click the ComboBoxColumn, the DataGridView does not respond unlike the other columns which are TextBoxColumns. Meaning, it does not sort when I click the column header.

How can I provide this feature or do I have to override the functionality of the column with my own custom class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just prototyped this very quickly, by adding an unbound DataGridView to a form, then adding four columns, two textbox columns and two combobox columns.

The entire code-behind is shown below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) dataGridView1.Columns[1];
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col2 = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[2];
        List<string> items = new List<string>(){"B", "C", "E", "A"};
        col.DataSource = items;
        col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
        col2.DataSource = items;
        col2.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"});
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "B", "C", "C", "F" });
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new string[] { "C", "B", "A", "A" });
    }        
}
```

The sorting is working perfectly for me in this very simple example.

You may need to post code examples to narrow down what the difference is in your code.

One possible I can think of is that I'm binding to a list of strings, not objects.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare.aspx) you can also provide your own custom handler for the SortCompare event.

Comment: Great! It's always struck me a quite stupid that the columns have different default sortmodes. Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://www.vb-tips.com/dbpages.aspx?ID=ddd3e9d2-0646-4703-ac8c-9c17fd41918e) or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/ac3bc943-f73b-4c45-b26b-4c55117af85e) Url help at all??

Quote from the above Url:

> The datagridview combobox column sorts
>   on value of the column it is bound
>   too.  If you are using a datagridview
>   to show the text representation of an
>   id when you sort the column it will be
>   on the id not the text.

Comment: I'm using an unbound DataGridView so this won't help unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I am sorting a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn by the value of the ComboBox text rather than the ID by, ordering the records in my ComboBox. I modified the source of the ComboBox to sort the records by the value displayed (ORDER BY [value_displayed] ASC/DESC) in SQL. This then means that the IDs of the records are in the same order as the values.

For example:

- Un-sorted ComboBox: 1: Fernando, 2: Alex, 3: Charlie
- Sorted ComboBox: 1: Alex, 2: Charlie, 3: Fernando

This means that, even though the DataGridView column sort is sorting based on the IDs, the text values are in the same order and therefore the column sort will be correct.